# Laravel 5 - laracasts generators

Tags: php, laravel, installation

Hi I have problem with install Laravel 5 Extended Generators

When I do in console

```
composer require laracasts/generators --dev
```

Console returns error

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Trait
>   'Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait' not found
>       PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project-app\vendor\laracasts\generators\src\Commands\MigrationMakeCommand.php on line 16
>       Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

my composer

```
"require": {
    "laracasts/generators": "dev-master as 1.1.4",
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "backpack/base": "^0.7.21",
    "backpack/crud": "^3.2",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"

},
"require-dev": {

    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"

},
```

Comment: Use just `"laracasts/generators": "dev-master",` then update and see !!

Comment: because there is a problem in the generator after updating laravel to 5.4 see [here](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended/issues/117)

Comment: When I add "laracasts/generators": "dev-master" console returns error.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Change AppNamespaceDetectorTrait to DetectsApplicationNamespace (use x 2) in:
vendor/laracasts/generators/src/Commands/MigrationMakeCommand.php

Use 'dev-master' in composer.phar and run 'composer update' to pull in fix in latest commit 4e9ce5d

```
require{
"laracasts/generators": "dev-master",
}
```